# How can i make my Telegram bot understand uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot("5918393858:AAFyk-FNWiVPpYHv7u9WojgsvYqzAyGt4LE")
API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == ("Hello").lower():
        photo = open('adel.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
    elif message.text == "id":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"your ID: {message.from_user.id}", parse_mode='html')
    elif message.text == "How are you?":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'I am fine , and you ?' )
    else:
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id," I don't understand any fucking shit ", parse_mode='html')
```

Hi everyone , so i'm trying to create a telegram boy with Python but as you can see ---> if message.text == ("Hello").lower():
i tried typing .lower() after the (Hello) message so that the bot understand both upper and lowercase but it doesn't work
What should i do ?

Comment: Did you mean `message.text.lower() == 'hello'`?

Answer (score 0):

To compare two strings case insensitive, you can convert both sides to lowercase:

```
if message.text.lower() == "Hello".lower():
```

If you also want to handle non Ascii strings, you should consider the [casefold](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) function:

```
if message.text.casefold() == "Hello".casefold():
```